# Homogeneous polynomials of degree 3 in two variables

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be the four-dimensional real vector space consisting of all homogeneous polynomials of degree 3 in two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $U$ be the set of all elements of $V$ which are of the form

$(a_{1}X+b_{1}Y)^{3}+(a_{2}X+b_{2}Y)^{3}+(a_{3}X+b_{3}Y)^{3}+(a_{4}X+b_{4}Y)^{3}$

where for $i=1, 2, 3, 4$ we have $a_{i}^{2}+b_{i}^{2}=1$.

Is it true that the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $V$ generated by all sets of the form $f+rU$ where $f\in V$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}, r>0$ contains every Borel set?

Comment: This question seems very familiar, but I can't quite place it.  Do you have some motivation for asking this question, or background on why it is interesting?

Comment: I did have a motivation for asking the question. I was interested in a question about the uniqueness of Polish group topologies on a semi-direct product of a simple Lie group with a vector space over R via one of its faithful representations. I'm afraid I can't remember all the details of exactly how this question came up but it would have helped me to prove the existence of a unique Polish group topology for a certain semi-direct product of Lie groups.